# Debugger tool in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

I want to find my mistake in GAMS model. I don't have any errors , but my model doesn't work well
Is there any debugging tools in GAMS ?( like debugger tools in other software, e.g MATLAB)

Best

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I have not come across any.

If you have no errors in GAMS, it rather points to a modelling problem rather than a GAMS one. GAMS is like any other programming/modelling software, what you put in is what you get out. However, there are some commands and some intuitive ways you can find out the problem with your model:

One common way is by using the *display* and *$stop* commands. If you have loops within your GAMS code, it is best to track the progress of the loop by displaying some key variables either to your .lst file or using *put* utility (also a nice tool). I use the *put* utility, and write the code to display key variables at each point of my code to identify where things may have gone wrong.
The *$stop* command terminates your GAMS code at the line in which it is written.

Hope this helps.